# Creating one parameter for multiple DB columns in ActiveRecord Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How would you go about linking up two columns with one parameter?

Say I have multiple user classes `Foo` and `Bar`.

They each have many `Child`s. `Child` belongs to one of the user classes.

I have two DB columns in `Child`, `user_type` and `user_id`. I would like to be able to update `Child` with its parent user by doing:

```
Child.first.update(user: Foo.first)
```

or

```
Child.first.update(user: Bar.first)
```

I've tried defining custom methods in the `ActiveRecord::Base` file of `Child`, but it only seems to be able to retrieve.

```
#child.rb
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base

def user
    if user_type == 'Foo'
        return Foo.find(user_id)
    elsif user_type == 'Bar'
        return Bar.find(user_id)
    end
end

def user=(parent)
    user_type = parent.class.base_class.name
    user_id = parent.id
end
```

Having the above code, `Child.first.user` works but `Child.first.update(user: Foo.first)` does not.

Comment: `user_type = parent.class.base_class.name` just creates a local variable, `self.user_type = parent.class.base_class.name` OTOH calls the `user_type=` method.

Comment: both of the statement has to be called with `self.`